# Copy value to clipboard

Tags: javascript, html

On my website i wanna create a button that copy the value of a input field

**JS File**

```
function copyClipBoard() {
    var copyText = document.getElementById('input');
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="your new password" disabled>
```

Is it because the input field is disabled? I've seen many examples with exact the same code but here it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `disabled` to `readonly` it should be working across all browsers generally.

Another workaround is:

```
function copy() {
    copyText = (document.getElementById('id'));
    copyText.disabled = false;
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('Copy');
    copyText.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It work! So i cannot use disabled on the input field? any workaround for?

Comment: Thanks mate! Works like a charm.